# Why does TCP exit out of slow-start faster than expected?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, linux

For context, I am testing a client-server TCP flow, where the client makes a request for a file, and the server sends the file using regular TCP streams. Both servers are using the "Cubic" implementation of congestion control for TCP.

For some reason, when I am analyzing the wireshark PCAPs, I see that after one CWND worth of packets is ACKED, this CWND is not doubled (or multiplied by some factor). It instead remains at the same CWND size. Later on, I see the value increasing, but in a linear way, not exponentially as it should occur through slow start.

Throughout my wireshark analysis of the PCAP files, I see no packet loss (no DUP acks, no missing segments, etc.). Is there any other diagnosis I should perform to see why the server decides to decrease the rate at which it increases the CWND?

Comment: Perhaps you should check the values for \alpha and \beta that are used in the cubic model